# Unity ARkit remote with iOS - just stuck on "waiting for editor connection"?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am very confused. I am just trying to run a simple ARKit app with Unity ARKit remote on my iPhone 7 - I have looked at all online tutorials/similar questions and despite having no error this time, all I get is the black screen "waiting for editor connection" on my iPhone, connected via USB to my mac.

[image]

I click the start remote button and nothing happens. I made sure to be on debug, this is My build settings for Unity:
[image]

Ive even tried going to Editor> project settings and selecting my iPhone. What am I doing wrong? I just want to debug my AR games on iPhone

Comment: Same problem here with the official ARKitRemote scene included in the plugin.

Comment: same here.... iOS 12, Unity 2018.3

Comment: it works on iOS 12, Unity 2018.3, iphones but not on my iPad 4